# What is the best way to get pass this common Solr error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

This error comes up if my computer has been on for awhile, and I've been toggling between different applications.

Normally if I perform `sunspot-solr stop` and `sunspot-solr start`, that is all that is required to get my server up and running happily.

But if the conditions I mentioned occured, then I get this :

```
Solr Response: Severe_errors_in_solr_configuration__Check_your_log_files_for_more_detailed_information_on_what_may_be_wrong__If_you_want_solr_to_continue_after_configuration_errors_change____abortOnConfigurationErrorfalseabortOnConfigurationError__in_null___javalangRuntimeException_javaioFileNotFoundException_no_segments_file_found_in_orgapachelucenestoreNIOFSDirectoryprivatevarfoldersDHDHXHq79mEpqXT6vQyzkhaETITmpindex_files_lucene0df3ec9bbc1f2dea7d43b32c37464540writelock__at_orgapachesolrcoreSolrCoregetSearcherSolrCorejava1068__at_orgapachesolrcoreSolrCoreinitSolrCorejava579__at_orgapachesolrcoreCoreContainer$InitializerinitializeCoreContainerjava137__at_orgapachesolrservletSolrDispatchFilterinitSolrDispatchFilterjava83__at_orgmortbayjettyservletFilterHolderdoStartFilterHolderjava99__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayjettyservletServletHandlerinitializeServletHandlerjava594__at_orgmortbayjettyservletContextstartContextContextjava139__at_orgmortbayjettywebappWebAppContextstartContextWebAppContextjava1218__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerContextHandlerdoStartContextHandlerjava500__at_orgmortbayjettywebappWebAppContextdoStartWebAppContextjava448__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerHandlerCollectiondoStartHandlerCollectionjava147__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerContextHandlerCollectiondoStartContextHandlerCollectionjava161__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerHandlerCollectiondoStartHandlerCollectionjava147__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerHandlerWrapperdoStartHandlerWrapperjava117__at_orgmortbayjettyServerdoStartServerjava210__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstra
```

The only workaround I've been able to find is to simply reboot my computer. Which I find is a trifle bit annoying.

Any ideas?

Comment: first time ive seen an error in paragraph form separated with underscores LOL

Answer (score 0):

Just what the error says, you're encountering I/O problems. Per this [old posting](http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-dev@lucene.apache.org/msg06519.html) on the solr-dev mailing list, it sounds like your index directory exists but the index files themselves do not.

If Solr finds the index directory, it assumes the index exists and starts trying to load index files.  Hence, the error.

Depending on the actual scenario with your start/stop routines, I would look at what happens with index files on start.

Comment: I'm curious where this particular folder is. Do you think it could be resolved by me just deleting that folder?

Comment: The solr index directory is configurable, not fixed. Check your solrconfig file - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#dataDir_parameter.